# Update the color of a progress bar in Python using a scale?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, progress-bar

I have a progress bar that changes its value according to the value I move a scale to. Now I want to make the progress bar change color in real-time depending on what value the scale is moved to. Here is the method I have created to do this:

```
def volumelevel():
    s = ttk.Style()
    s.theme_use("classic")
    if scalevar.get() <= 25:
        s.configure("green.Horizontal.TProgressbar", background='green')
        scale.configure(variable=scalevar, command=lambda x: progress.configure(value=scalevar.get()))
        progress.configure(style="green.Horizontal.TProgressbar")
    elif scalevar.get() <= 75:
        s.configure("yellow.Horizontal.TProgressbar", background='yellow')
        scale.configure(variable=scalevar, command=lambda x: progress.configure(value=scalevar.get()))
        progress.configure(style="yellow.Horizontal.TProgressbar")
    elif scalevar.get() <= 90:
        s.configure("orange.Horizontal.TProgressbar", background='orange')
        scale.configure(variable=scalevar, command=lambda x: progress.configure(value=scalevar.get()))
        progress.configure(style="orange.Horizontal.TProgressbar")
    elif scalevar.get() <= 100:
        s.configure("red.Horizontal.TProgressbar", background='red')
        scale.configure(variable=scalevar, command=lambda x: progress.configure(value=scalevar.get()))
        progress.configure(style="red.Horizontal.TProgressbar")
```

I know this method does work because I called it inside a button to test it and when I adjust the scale and then click the button, the progress bar color changes.

I am calling this method in my scale object, but when I move the scale slider, the progress bar stays green (as specified in the method) regardless of the value the scale is set to. How can I get the progress bar color to change in real-time with the scale?

**UPDATE:** I made a tkinter entry to display the values in real time with the scale, then made the method change the foreground of the entry depending on the values and it works for some reason, but yet with the progress bar it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I started playing around with the method and I think the issue was that there was a lot of redundancy inside it (I'm still learning) which caused some conflict. I took a gamble and started removing small sections of code at a time to see how the method behaved and found the main problem was in my scale configurations. After removing unneeded code the method looks as follows:

```
def volumelevel():
    if scalevar.get() <= 25:
        s.configure("Horizontal.TProgressbar", background='green')
        progress.configure(style="Horizontal.TProgressbar", value=scalevar.get())
    elif scalevar.get() <= 75:
        s.configure("Horizontal.TProgressbar", background='yellow')
        progress.configure(style="Horizontal.TProgressbar", value=scalevar.get())
    elif scalevar.get() <= 90:
        s.configure("Horizontal.TProgressbar", background='orange')
        progress.configure(style="Horizontal.TProgressbar", value=scalevar.get())
    elif scalevar.get() <= 100:
        s.configure("Horizontal.TProgressbar", background='red')
        progress.configure(style="Horizontal.TProgressbar", value=scalevar.get())
```

I had the `Style()` declaration, and the theme in the root portion of my code (from a previous example I found) so I took that out.

I took the color name out of the name of my styles as this had no effect on the method.

I took the scale configurations out completely as the attributes were being called in the scale object itself and therefore I used the command inside my scale object to call the method I created instead of set the value of the progress bar.

And now the progress bar changes color in real time based on the value of the scale.